# Weird output from "flutter clean" command when used outside folder that has build

Tags: flutter

When i run flutter clean a folder outside the main build folder. I this response:

Changing current working directory to: /User/..

Why is that? and what does working directory refer to? How do i know my old one?

Comment: Can you include an image, and is there any issue on `flutter doctor -v`

Comment: "Current working directory" just means the current directory (the directory you were "working" in). `flutter clean` presumably is changing the current directory to try to find the root directory of your Flutter project.  If you're not in a Flutter project, it's going to be confused.

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be a yaml file for `flutter clean` to work correctly.
That was my mistake.